# DOM elements exist in two places at once? (bysynchronisation)

Tags: javascript, dom

Strange question I know, but is there anyway in Javascript or anyother web-based language to make the same DOM element exist in two places at once?

Comment: No. You can clone an element though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gecko-based renderers let you render the same element in multiple places with the [element()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/element) CSS function.
Note that this only renders the element as image, it does not propagate events backwards to the source element.

Comment: That's actually super useful, is there anyway to do something with event-listeners as well?

Comment: @AndrewHansen capture and manually re-dispatch those that you need. but that is very tedious and brittle, I would advise against it.

Answer (score 2):

> The DOM is the DOM, regardless of language.

Each DOM element is either not connected to DOM at all or connected to one specific parent. You cannot display same element in two different places. Attaching to a new parent will just move element from old one.

You can **create or clone** element, that is the same through a `Node`.

```js
function clone() {
  var itm = document.getElementById("items-one").lastChild;
  var cln = itm.cloneNode(true);
  document.getElementById("items-two").appendChild(cln);
}
```

```html
<ul id="items-one"><li>Element One</li></ul>
<ul id="items-two"><li>Element Two</li></ul>

<button onclick="clone()">Clone Element</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends what you call "*exists*".

In SVG, there is the [`<use>`](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/struct.html#UseElement) element, which allows to create deep clones of a reference node in the ShadowTree of the host `<use>` element. You'd say yeah, it's just cloning, **but**, this clone has the particularity of being deeply linked to its source. DOM modifications made on the source will affect the clone, CSS rules applied on the source will also affect the clone <sub>at least in SVG2</sub>:

```js
onclick = e => // we only modify the source #rect
  document.getElementById('rect').setAttribute("height", 20);
```

```css
:hover #rect{
  fill: red;  /*Firefox is buggy here*/
}
```

```html
click to execute DOM modification
<svg>
  <rect id="rect" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" fill="green"/>
  <use x="60" xlink:href="#rect"/>
</svg>
```

So technically, the source fragment only exists in one place in the DOM, and it is simply cloned every time. However, given the deep link, for the consumer, it is very close to having it existing in two places at the same time.

Other SVG elements can also get **rendered** multiple times while existing in a single place in the DOM. `<marker>`, and `<pattern>` are such elements:

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <!-- defined only once -->
    <marker id="dot" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="5" refY="5"
        markerWidth="5" markerHeight="5">
      <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5" fill="red" />
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <!-- our marker will get painted twice -->
  <polyline points="10,10 10,90 90,90" fill="none" stroke="black"
   marker-start="url(#dot)" marker-end="url(#dot)"  />
</svg>
```

So once again, it can be said that they do *"exist"* multiple times, but in the DOM, they are only once. (really like FF's `element()`
*the8472* mentioned in their answer).

---

Now if you only mean *exists* as in `node1 !== node2 && node1.childNodes[0] === node2.childNodes[0]` then no.